# Delete files that is not in my XML document with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file that contains the SKU of products. I also have a folder that corresponds to this XML file.

```
Snippet from XML:
<Feed>
  <Product>
    <ItemCode>ALT-AAB-BL</ItemCode>
    <BaseItemCode>ALT-AAB</BaseItemCode>
    <StockCheckCode>ALT-AAB-BL</StockCheckCode>
 </Product>
  <Product>
    <ItemCode>ALT-AAB-L</ItemCode>
    <BaseItemCode>ALT-AAB</BaseItemCode>
    <StockCheckCode>ALT-AAB-L</StockCheckCode>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <ItemCode>ALT-AAB-N</ItemCode>
    <BaseItemCode>ALT-AAB</BaseItemCode>
    <StockCheckCode>ALT-AAB-N</StockCheckCode>
 </Product>
</Feed>
```

I have been trying it with php but I am a junior and dont know where to start so I will give you some pseudo code.

```
if $domelement->ItemCode != filename.jpg{
    delte.jpg;
}
```

Yes this pseudo code is terrible. I basically am able to pull in the .xml file and was able to manipulate data.

I basically want to delete the files that is not present in the xml file and preserve the rest. I know how to appedn the ItemCode with .png if I need to.

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->load('altitude.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$query = sprintf('/Feed/Product/BaseItemCode');

foreach($xpath->query($query) as $record) {
//delete file that is not present in BaseItemCode
}
```

I just want the files not present in xml->BaseItemCode (which I will append with .png or .jpg) to be deleted from the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two lists: whitelist from XML and all items list from system.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->load('altitude.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$query = sprintf('/Feed/Product/BaseItemCode');
$xmlList = [];

foreach($xpath->query($query) as $record) {
    $xmlList[] = $record->ItemCode . '.jpg';
    $xmlList[] = $record->ItemCode . '.png'; // If you can, use smarter way
}
```

---

```
$directory = '/full/path/to/dir';
$dirList = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));

$filesToDelete = array_diff($dirList, $xmlList);

foreach ($filesToDelete as $file) {
    unlink($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working but I am getting an error. PHP Notice:  Undefined property: DOMElement::$ItemCode in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/promoworld-images-delete/delete-images.php on line 12

Comment: @AntonRoos So it means your `$record` does not have property `ItemCode`, debug this place

Comment: When I var_dump($dirList); I get the correct data [2]=> string(13) "11-001(2).png" [3]=> string(13) "11-001(3).png" [4]=> string(13) "11-001(4).png" [5]=> string(20) "11-001-BACK-2013.png" [6]=> string(13)... However when I var_dump($xmlList) I get [0]=> string(4) ".png" [1]=> string(4) ".png" [2]=> string(4) ".png"...

Comment: I tried changing ItemCode to parentNode and got: PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string

Answer (score 0):

@justinas 's method worked. I had this weird space at the end of every single array element imported from my CSV file. I converted my XML to a CSV file and used it as an array.

```
<?php

$csv = file('convertcsv.csv');

function test_alter(&$item1, $key, $prefix)
{
    $item1 = "$item1$prefix";

}

array_walk($csv, 'test_alter', '.png');
//var_dump($csv);

$directory = 'img';
$dirList = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));


$filesToDelete = array_diff($dirList, $csv);

foreach ($filesToDelete as $file) {
    unlink($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
}
echo "klaar"


?>
```

Can anyone tell me why there is a blank space after every single element in the array if you use:

```
$csv = file('convertcsv.csv');
```

as an array?